# The sum of derivatives at $0$.

Tags: analysis

Does the following expression on the space $\mathcal D(\mathbb{R})$, define a distribution: $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\varphi^{(n)}(0)\;\;?$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: I think its not, the series might not converge, but i can't find a counterexample

Comment: What's an obvious smooth function for which it diverges? Can you modify the function away from $0$ to make it an eligible $\varphi$?

Comment: Does $(1+x)e^{1/(x^2-1)}$ on [-1,1] and 0 otherwise work?

Comment: I don't think so. Perhaps you don't need to be quite so explicit. Allow yourself to use a bump function without writing a formula for it.

Comment: I need a bump function for which the derivatives at 0 give something the diverges

Comment: No you don't. Wrong idea about the bump function.

Comment: If you consider a locally analytic function with Maclaurin coefficients: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\cdot x^n$$Then the action of your expression on this function is: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!\cdot a_n$$

This might help you exploit prof. Shifrin's hint. You can make that series diverge fairly easily. You just need to smooth it out to have compact support

Comment: If $\varphi$ is a smooth function which is 1 around 0 then $\varphi.\exp$ have all derivatives equal 1 at 0, so the series diverges

Comment: Yes, sphinx, that's where I hoped you would go. You just need to say that $\varphi$ is $1$ on a neighborhood of $0$ and compactly supported.

Comment: Thank you very much Professor Shifrin